# I'm trying to serve my react app from express, why am I getting a 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have a react app being built to my project's /dist directory, I'm trying to serve the bundle and required files via my express server, as well as connect to mongo and provide an api for some data there.

Right now I'm unable to get my app to load. I am getting an error `GET http://localhost:5000/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` at localhost:5000

Below is my server file and the rest of the project is [here](https://github.com/int-a/contacts/tree/static-contacts-list)

server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes/api');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//connect to the database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log(`Database connected successfully`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// overide mongoose promise (depricated) with node's promise
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // TODO: should header be set on res or req?
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', routes);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../index.html'));
});

app.use('/../dist', express.static('dist'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: shouldn't that last `app.use(...)` go before your routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. Although I'd suggest switching over to my [fullstack-mern-kit](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit), but that's up for you to decide.

Anyway, follow these steps...

In the `package.json` change `scripts` to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

In your `dist` folder, add an `index.html` (you'll also need include a `<link>` to your compiled `css` stylesheet):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Minimal React Webpack Babel Setup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your `server.js` file, rework it like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");

app.get("/sampleData", (req, res) => {
  res.send("sample data");
});

app.use(express.static("dist"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(resolve("dist", "index.html")));

app.listen(8080);
```

Run `npm run build`, then `npm start`, then navigate to `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Why the if block? I'm not setting that environment variable. Should I be? I'm not exactly productionizing this right now, but I see how it would be useful. Why wouldn't I want this to execute when in development mode?

Comment: This assumes you're using `webpack-dev-server` for `development` and `webpack` for `production`. If not, then don't use the if statement.

Comment: Here's an example implementation: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. It's still giving a 404 in production mode though. I haven't set up webpack dev server so I'm using built versions to test.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm actually using this app as a learning tool for the mern stack, trying to build it from scratch without using any sort of bootstraping project. Your sample looks like it will be very helpful.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. Things are up and running now. Definitely nice having the dev server in there too :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to build the app first. Use this command and then try serving: `npm run build`